# Bootstrap responsive Table -> change Rows with Column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, html-table

I have a problem creating a timetable for my school using Bootstrap.
The timetable should be responsive for mobile devices and tablets.

The view for larger screens works perfectly, but when it switches to the mobile View, it changes the rows with columns ..

Tabletview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qniYC.png
[image]

Mobileview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qniYC.png#1
[image]

The main html File:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
#no-more-tables table,
#no-more-tables thead,
#no-more-tables tbody,
#no-more-tables th,
#no-more-tables td,
#no-more-tables tr {
display: block;
}
 
/* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
#no-more-tables thead tr {
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
}
 
#no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
  
#no-more-tables td {
/* Behave like a "row" */
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
position: relative;
padding-left: 50%;
white-space: normal;
text-align:left;
}
 
#no-more-tables td:before {
/* Now like a table header */
position: absolute;
/* Top/left values mimic padding */
top: 6px;
left: 6px;
width: 45%;
padding-right: 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align:left;
font-weight: bold;
}
 
/*
Label the data
*/
#no-more-tables td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Timetable</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="js/bootstrap.js" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- <link src="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
 
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="text-center">
                Timetable
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="no-more-tables">
            <table class="col-sm-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
          <thead class="cf">
           <tr>
      <th>      </th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">07:45 |1| 08:35</td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">08:35 |2| 09:25</td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">09:30 |3| 10:20</td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">10:35 |4| 11:25</td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">11:30 |5| 12:20</td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">12:20 |6| 13:10</td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">13:10 |7| 14:00</td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">14:00 |8| 14:50</td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">15:00 |9| 15:50</td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">15:55 |10| 16:45 </td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">16:50 |11| 17:40 </td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
     <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">17:40 |12| 18:30 </td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
     <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">18:55 |13| 19:40 </td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
     <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">19:40 |14| 20:25 </td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
     <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">20:30 |15| 21:15 </td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
     <tr>
      <td data-title="      ">21:15 |16| 22:00 </td>
            <td data-title="Monday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Tuesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Wednesday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Thursday">Lesson</td>
            <td data-title="Friday">Lesson</td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Did anyone know, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Replace your html code lines

`<div id="no-more-tables">` with `<div class="table-responsive">`

and

`<table class="col-sm-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">` with `<table class="table col-sm-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">`

See working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rxbaoj1r/)

Comment: This approach works width small data if the text is big it goes out the column.