# How to make table mobile responsive - grouping data by column rather than row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have a table in the following table header format...

Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday

Below each I am populating with shifts by going through each row...
With bootstrap responsive tables it will sort it by each row...
My question is, is there a way I can make it display SUNDAY- then all Sunday shifts, then below that MONDAY with Monday shifts and so on?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you using any server side technology like PHP or .NET?

Comment: yeah im using php i can populate the table no problem. When it goes to a mobile phone size i want the table to display with sunday header first, followed by all sundays shifts, then mondays header, followed by all mondays shift an so on. When it is a normal screen i can easily echo out each row for each

Comment: Maybe this could be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046506/bootstrap-responsive-table-change-rows-with-column?rq=1