# How to make Responsive table for smart phone view using bootstrap 4 and css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make a responsive table. As I'm done with my table with a desktop view.
Now I want the table should be responsive so for smartphone users the table should visible properly.

My table looks for the website is something like this:

[image]

and my code is:

**main.html**

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr class="table-dark">
                <th></th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Name2</th>
                <th>Name3</th>
                <th>Name4</th>
                <th>Name5</th>  
                <th>Name6</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Button</th>  
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>   
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <img id="brandimg" alt="" src="">
                </td>
                <td><a href=""></a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button> 
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Now I want to make a table responsive as said earlier for smartphone , something like this:

[image]

how to make it with bootstrap 4 and help with css?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046506/bootstrap-responsive-table-change-rows-with-column

Comment: Example in that post here http://jsfiddle.net/rxbaoj1r/

Comment: Yes something like this

Answer (score 1):

I think that grid is the best way for a responsive table
just something like this

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.title {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 900;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .table {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .title {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .row > div {
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <span class="title">title 1</span>
      Content
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="title">title 2</span>
      Content
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="title">title 3</span>
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <span class="title">title 4</span>
      Content
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="title">title 5</span>
      Content
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="title">title 6</span>
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and modify according to your need.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container table-responsive py-5">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">5</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: its already done. As per given second image I want that